# How to View/Debug Kubernetes Custom Metric Values (custom.metrics.k8s.io)?

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am using [this](https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) to export metrics from Prometheus to Kubernetes. That seems to be working. I can (successfully) see the metric names with

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq '.'
```

This shows the names of the metrics, but doesn't show the values. How do I see the values?

I intend to use this with a HorizontalPodAutoscaler. I'd like to see what the metric values look like within the Kubernetes Metric System to assist in understanding and configuring this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific for the Kubernetes API.

If you deployed everything correctly and everything is working as it should when you use

```
$ kubectl get --raw="/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq
```

you should get list of `MetricValues` if you have any metrics added.

Here is a really good article about [Building Kubernetes Apps with Scaling on Custom Metrics: A Gentle Introduction](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-kubernetes-apps-with-custom-scaling-a-gentle-introduction-a332d7ebc795).

You mentioned that your intend is to use the metrics for [HorizontalPodAutoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), I would strongly recommend going over [Kubernetes pod autoscaler using custom metrics](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-autoscaler/) as it provides some really nice examples on how to create and use custom metrics.